# renew message lock on Azure Bus in Spring application

Tags: spring, azure, azureservicebus, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder

We have an application that uses the [Spring Cloud Azure Stream Binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-with-service-bus) to consume messages from the Azure Bus.

Our consumer looks like the one in the official documentation:

```
import com.azure.spring.messaging.checkpoint.Checkpointer;
[...]

import static com.azure.spring.messaging.AzureHeaders.CHECKPOINTER;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceBusApplication {


    [...] 

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<String>> consume() {
        return message -> {
            Checkpointer checkpointer = (Checkpointer) message.getHeaders().get(CHECKPOINTER);
           
            checkpointer.success()
                        .doOnSuccess(s -> LOGGER.info("Message '{}' successfully checkpointed", message.getPayload()))
                        .doOnError(e -> LOGGER.error("Error found", e))
                        .block();
        };
    }
}
```

We need to programmatically [renew the message lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#renew-locks) if the consumer needs more time to process the message.

This can be done using the API [com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient.renewMessageLock()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiverasyncclient?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusreceiverasyncclient-renewmessagelock(com-azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusreceivedmessage))

But I was unable to grab a reference to the ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient object.
Is this possible to do this operation using the Spring binder without reimplementing the code to us the azure java sdk directly?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the behaviour is that the lock is automatically renewed up to `max-auto-lock-renew-duration` if the message is not consumed until then (or consuming finishes with exception). The lock is initially held for 1 minute, then it is renewed.

Although this is not well documented in the spring cloud doc, this article may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement